# Issues with the width of height with loading an page with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a little problem. I am using Jquery to load an HTML into a `Div` but for some strange reason the width and the height does not automatically rezies to the div height and width. This is the code:

```
$("#middlebox").html('<object data="http://tired.com/">');
```

Does anyone know how I can fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try

```
    $("#middlebox").load('http://tired.com/', function() {
    alert( "Load was performed." );
  });
```

reference **[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**

Comment: Yeah - I have been testing these answers in JS fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/WtLE8/

Comment: But the text isn't loaded - you can't see it. :P

Comment: try in your html jsfiddle not allow this

Comment: developerproject.x10.mx/index.html ? Or are you saying something else.

Comment: no load url is what tired.com/home.html or tired.com/index.html